# Label goes out of nested frame when using grid (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

It is only a simple question but shouldn't a label stay inside of it's nested frame when you use sticky ? In my code it only stays in the parent frame. If it is normal do you have a solution ?

I have tried looking the documentation but I didn't find anything which could help.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Tk test")
root.geometry("800x800")

frame_1 = ttk.Frame(root, relief="sunken", height="400", width="400").grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1)
frame_2 = ttk.Frame(frame_1, relief="sunken", height="200", width="200").grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1)
label_1 = ttk.Label(frame_2, text="Text").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="N, E")

root.mainloop()
```

Expected result : The label stays inside of it's frame which is nested inside the parent frame.
Actual results : It only stays inside the parent frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.grid(...)` function returns `None`. Therefore, when you do

```
frame_1 = ttk.Frame(root, relief="sunken", height="400", width="400").grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1)
```

you assign `None` to `frame_1`. And the same goes for `frame_2` and `label_1`.

Because `frame_1 == None`, calling `ttk.Frame(frame_1, ...)` is actually the same as `ttk.Frame(None, ...)`. Therefore, you're not passing a master, which defaults to having the root window as the master. Again, the same goes for the creation of `label_1`.

The fix is to split the creation and placement of the widgets to two separate lines:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Tk test")
root.geometry("800x800")

frame_1 = ttk.Frame(root, relief="sunken", height="400", width="400")
frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1)
frame_2 = ttk.Frame(frame_1, relief="sunken", height="200", width="200")
frame_2.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1)
label_1 = ttk.Label(frame_2, text="Text")
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="N, E")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I normally do it in two separate lines too. But what is the difference between doing it on the same line and in two separate lines ?

Comment: When you chain functions, python will return the value of the last function. For example, `' '.join(['a', 'b'])` returns `'a b'`, but`' '.join(['a', 'b']).split()` returns `['a', 'b']`. In the same way, `ttk.Frame(...)` returns a Frame object, but `ttk.Frame(...).grid(...)` returns `None`, because that is the return value of `grid`. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/3714930).

Answer (score -2):

add .pack() at the end of each line where you define frame_1, frame_2 and label_1